# Javafx maven plugin. Проблема с кирилицей в пути к созданному exe файлу

Tags: maven, javafx, кириллица, exe

Добрый день. У меня есть Javafx приложение, которое собирается в exe файл с помощью javafx maven plugin. На компьютерах, где отсутствует JVM, приложение запускается только если в пути к файлу нет кириллицы. Возможно это исправить?

Вот конфигурация плагина:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
               <goal>jar</goal>
               <goal>native</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>ru.janeerr.gmwn.Main</mainClass>
        <nativeOutputDir>app/win</nativeOutputDir>
        <jfxAppOutputDir>app/jfx</jfxAppOutputDir>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```